# Read and Write text file from my own class in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, class

I have been trying to create a class called `TextFileReaderWriter` I want to use the getters and setters to read and write to a text file in such a way that I can call the class and the method from anywhere in the program by simply using `setfileContents(somestring)` and `somestring = getfileContents()` something like this
example:

```
TextFileReaderWriter trw = new TextFileReaderWriter();
trw.setfileContents(somestring); //this would write 'somestring' to the text file.
String somestring = trw.getfileContents(); //this would return 'somestring' from the text file.
```

Here's what I have so far but it writes nothing to the file:

```
public class TextFileReaderWriter extends Activity{

            String fileContents;
            Context context;
            String TAG = "MYTAG";

    public TextFileReaderWriter(String fileContents, Context context) {
        this.fileContents = fileContents;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String getFileContents() {
        return fileContents;
    }

    public void setFileContents(String fileContents) {
        this.fileContents = fileContents;

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = context.openFileOutput("UserInputStore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);

        try {
            osw.write(fileContents);
            Log.d(TAG, fileContents);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: what your logcat says? anyway, first your getfilecontent didnt read your file, it reads your variable filecontent, second you write in private folder of your app

Comment: Are you intentionally trying to store it internal storage, or did you mean to go for external? Also, your `getFileContents()` doesn't actually return the file contents; when you restart your app (or the activity, even), the data will be gc'd.

Comment: I have not written the getFileContents as of yet, I was only working with the setFileContents method.... the problem right now is that it's not writing the string I pass into it to the file. It does create the file but it's empty.

Comment: @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        TextFileReaderWriter write = new TextFileReaderWriter(writetext.getText().toString(), getBaseContext());
        write.setFileContents(writetext.getText().toString());
        Log.d(TAG, writetext.getText().toString());
    }

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `OutputStreamWriter`--`FileOutputStream`will do the trick just fine.

```
    //what you had before
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //use just the file output stream to write the data
    //data here is a String
    if (fos != null) {
        try {
            fos.write(data.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Method to save data on disk :

```
protected static void saveDataOnDisk(String data) {

ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

try {

ObjectOutput objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);

objectOutput.writeObject(data);

byte[] buffer = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

File loginDataFile = (new File(filePath)); // file path where you want to write your data

loginDataFile.createNewFile();

FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(loginDataFile);

fileOutputStream.write(buffer);

fileOutputStream.close();

objectOutput.flush();

objectOutput.close();

byteArrayOutputStream.flush();

byteArrayOutputStream.close();

Log.i(“SAVE”, ”———————-DONE SAVING”);

} catch(IOException ioe) {

Log.i(“SAVE”, “———serializeObject|”+ioe);

}

}
```

Method to fetch data from disk:

```
private static Object getDataFromDisk() {

try {

FileInputStream fileInputeStream = new FileInputStream(FilePath);

ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputeStream);

Object data = (Object) objectInputStream.readObject();

objectInputStream.close();

fileInputeStream.close();

return dataModel;

} catch (Exception error) {

Log.i(“FETCH”, ”—-getDataFromDisk———ERROR while reading|” + error);

}

return null;

}
```